# create a style hook outside of main page for overlay event handler

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create an overlay that appears on the right hand side of the page when the user hovers on the right hand side of the page outside the main area. I'm struggling to come up with a way to fire the event when the user hovers outside the main area on the right side. Some sort of element needs to be attached to the outside of the right side of the middle section that stretches the full length of the of the body. I'm not sure how to apply this element.

I've looked for solutions online and thought about absolute positioning the element somehow but found nothing that works. It seems like it should be quite a simple thing to do !

How can I add an element that'll fit variying window widths and remain in the same place ?

apologies if the explanation is not entirely clear I've added a jsfiddle as an example.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">


    <div class="middlesection">



    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
background:#fff;
}

.middlesection {
width:300px;
height:500px;
background:#00c;
margin:0 auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M7Bn9/

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/26f2204fd5858168ade58dae9914b9a4/).

You would give the overlay fixed positioning and put it on the right hand side of the screen. You could hide it with opacity or a transform, and reveal on hover.